# Using Jenkins as graphical frontend - parametrized builds

Tags: jenkins

I have a few build scripts which can be run from the command line. I'd like to have a web UI to run them and I thought about using Jenkins. I see that the Jenkins job supports parameters and then defined parameters are set as environment variables in the build environment. However, I would not like to have to alter my scripts to accept input from environment variables, it would be easier to continue to accept input from command line. I thought about adding the following shell command to the Jenkins job:

```
eg <build_script> --option1 $JENKINS_PARAM1 --option2 $JENKINS_PARAM2
```

Then, I would not need to alter my existing build scripts. Is that a common/recommended usage of Jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This seems to be perfectly fine for me.